# Are K and V values reused in each decoder layer's cross-Attention in the original "Attention is all you need" paper?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, transformer, attention

I'm working with Transformers and have a question about the encoder-decoder structure. In each decoder layer's cross-attention, are the K and V pairs from the corresponding encoder layer reused for all cross-attention operations within that decoder layer? Or are they recalculated for each operation?

Also, if K and V are reused, doesn't this limit the decoder's effectiveness? It seems like only the Query values are changing and propagating through the model. Since most of the meaning is stored in the V layer, wouldn't using the same K and V hinder the decoder's abilities?